# What are the advantages/disadvantages of assigning a name to one or more of the properties a LINQ anonymous type?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

In the example below I have assigned the name “CustomerType” to the property x.Preferred.

Apart from maybe gaining readability, are there any performance advantages/disadvantages in assigning a name to a property?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Preferred { get; set; }

        // Constructor that takes one argument:
        public Customer(string _name, string _iD, string _preferred)
        {
            Name = _name;
            ID = _iD;
            Preferred = _preferred;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Customer[] cust = new Customer[]
            {
                new Customer ("Mike", "1234", "Preferred"),
                new Customer ("Alice", "4321", "Preferred"),
                new Customer ("Susan", "3214", "Not Preferred"),
                new Customer ("David", "7538", "Preferred")
            };
            var customers = cust
                            .Where(x => x.Preferred == "Not Preferred")
                            .Select(x => new
                            {
                                x.Name,                              
                                x.ID,
                                CustomerType = x.Preferred            //  What are the advantages/disavantages of assigning the name "CustomerType" to this property?
                            });
            foreach (var customer in customers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"  Preferred Customer is {customer.Name}.  Customer ID  is {customer.ID}.   Customer is {customer.CustomerType}.\n  ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would a name affect performance?

Comment: The name has to be recorded somewhere - it is an additional data item after all.

Comment: No, there always is a name (default or custom) and that is a compile-time thing. You won't be able to observe any difference at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Anonymous Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) specification

> If you do not specify member names in the anonymous type, the compiler
>   gives the anonymous type members the same name as the property being
>   used to initialize them. You must provide a name for a property that
>   is being initialized with an expression

So, this just a naming convenience, nothing in terms of performance. You specify the name you want instead of original property name.

In your code it means that you are using `CustomerType` name of `Preferred` property from original `Customer` object. If you write your `Select` expression like this

```cs
x => new
{
    x.Name,                              
    x.ID,
    x.Preferred
}
```

You can access the last property only by `Preferred` name. But you have to specify the name, when anonymous type is a result of expression, for example

```cs
x => new
{
    x.Name,                              
    Count = x.Count() //will not compile without name
}
```

Comment: @Joe does it answer your question, do you need more details or information?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response Pavel.  Yes, your suggestion is fine.  Thanks.